# multiple ros release support in rosdep.yaml

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [modular_cloud_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/modular_cloud_matcher) package requires yaml-cpp, which is installed in the ros-wide rosdep.yaml in electric but not in diamondback. For the latter, I had put an entry in our rosdep.yaml:

```
yaml-cpp:
ubuntu: yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev
```

This entry solves the problem for diamondback, but creates [a conflict in electric](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ros-mapping/issues/2):

```
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: QUITTING: due to conflicting rosdep definitions, please resolve this conflict.
Rules for yaml-cpp do not match:
{'apt': {'packages': ['yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev']}} [/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml]
yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev [/opt/ros_addons/electric/stacks/ethzasl_mapping/rosdep.yaml]
```

Is there a way to specify rules specific to different ros releases in rosdep.yaml?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11741/multiple-ros-release-support-in-rosdep.yaml/) by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the rules are identical, then the conflict will not arise.  However, rosdep does not process the raw rule, so the rules have to structurally the same (i.e. apt->packages-> yamlcpp0.2.26-dev vs. 'yamlcpp-0.2.6-dev').

There is no way to make the rules distro-specific.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4